# Python scrape crytocompare

Tags: python, web-scraping, cryptography, bitcoin

I am trying to use python to scrape crytocompare output of "profit per month". The website uses javascript to get the output.

Currently I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/xmr?HashingPower=65&HashingUnit=H%2Fs&PowerConsumption=0&CostPerkWh=0.12&MiningPoolFee=.5")
p_element = driver.find_element_by_id(id_='ng-binding')
print(p_element.text)
```

The error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 49
    warnings.warn('Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless '
UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead
```

The issue I have with this is, I will be using Python 3.6 AWS Lambda Function

https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/aws-lambda-python-3-6.html. I don't believe I can install a headless version of Chrome/Firefox?

Is the above overkill to get the output I want? Please help

Comment: If you plan to deploy inside of Lambda, you are better off using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: FYI, I don't believe https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/ will help.

Comment: With javascript?

Comment: Ah good point, that won't work if it's generated content. You could try running running a container in ECS that comes packed with chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are trying is a total overkill.
A simple query to the API will give you all the needed information:

https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/coin/generalinfo?fsyms=%20BTC,ETH,ETC,XMR,ZEC,AION,PASC,DASH,LTC,DCR&tsym=USD

(you can test it in the browser)

The data needed in the calculations for each currency are: `NetHashesPerSecond, BlockTime, BlockReward`

And you can find all the calculations performed by the page in this javascript file:

https://www.cryptocompare.com/scripts/services/mining.js (chrome displays it nicely formatted)

Check the function `$scope.generateValues`.

It should be easy to translate these calculations to python.

I hope it helps!

PS: how I find the relevant js file? if you debug the page with your browser you'll find all the code in this file `https://www.cryptocompare.com/DependencyHandler.axd?s=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&t=Javascript`

I'm not an expert, but this looks the way Angular download the javascript dependencies, if you base64 decode that param you'll see:

`/scripts/Vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js;/scripts/Vendor/angular.1.5.5.min.js;/scripts/Vendor/extra-angular-modules.js;/scripts/initangularapp.js;/scripts/Vendor/socket.io-2.0.3.js;/scripts/Vendor/hover-dropdown.js;/scripts/streaming-utilities.js;/scripts/services/global.js;/scripts/controllers/global.js;/scripts/directives/global.js;/scripts/global.js;/scripts/routes/mining-calculator-page.js;/scripts/services/mining.js;/scripts/controllers/mining.js;/scripts/directives/mining.js;`

and all those files are available to download.

Cheers.

Comment: Please note that this api is subject to some conditions, read https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/

Comment: Awesome . Thanks. I found the monthly profit equation. However from the scripts above I can't find how they found the difficulty. Does anyone know what  NethasesPerseond would be used for? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/18629/what-is-the-algorithm-to-create-a-bitcoin-mining-calculator

Comment: The only thing the above doesnt tell me is the difficulty.